# Resistivity of electrolytes

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

My book mentions how can I find the resistivity of metals but can somebody Pls explain how can one find the resistivity/conductivity in case of electrolytes

Comment: Are you asking for a theoretical or experimental determination?

Answer (score 1):

The conductivity of an electrolyte is due to mobile ions present in the solution. For example in a salt solution the conductivity is due to the motion of $\text{Na}^+$ and $\text{Cl}^-$ ions.

To calculate the conductivity you need to know the mobility of the ions. This can be found from tables of experimentally measured mobilities. It isn't possible to calculate the mobilities from first principles so you need to look them up.

Once you have the ion conductivities the total conductivity is just given by summing up the conductivities of all the ions present:

$$ \kappa = \sum \kappa_i C_i $$

where $\kappa_i$ is the conductivity of ion $i$ and $C_i$ is its concentration. The sum is over all the ions present.

Note that traditionally the ion conductivity and concentration are [molal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molality) i.e. the concentration is moles per kilogram. Take care to check what units are used in any tables you look at.

Note also that conductivities are temperature and concentration dependent. The tables will normally give empirical equations for calculating the conductivity at whatever temperature and concentration you are using.

Comment: Can we use resistivity = R*A / l

Comment: @user194517: Yes, but you need to know the resitivity, and my answer describes how to calculate that. The resistivity is the reciprocal of the conductivity.